# Question regarding a proof of Fatou's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to see why the part in RED is true. This is what I got so far: let $x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k  \implies x \in A_k $ for some $k$. But $A_k \subseteq \mathbb{R} $. To see the other other direction, suppose $x \notin \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k $. Then $x \in ( \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k )^c $. Hence $x \in \bigcap_k A^c_k \implies x \in A^c_k \; \; \forall k \implies x \notin A_k \; \; \forall k \implies g_k < \overline{\phi} \implies $ can we conclude here that there is no $x$ that satisfies this inequality and hence $ x \in \varnothing $ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_k$ is the set for which $g_k$ beats $\bar{\varphi}$ (in the sense that $g_{k} \geq \bar{\varphi}$). $g_k$ is a sequence of functions approaching $f$ pointwise, and $f$ is strictly larger than $\bar{\varphi}$. The assertion

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k} = \mathbb{R}$$

is equivalent to stating that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is some sufficiently large $k$ such that $g_{k}(x) \geq \bar{\varphi}(x)$. Can you see how this follows from the way we chose these functions?

Comment: But Can you give me some feedback into my approach? IS it wrong?

Comment: Your approach is not necessarily wrong, it is just very roundabout and you don't explicitly end by saying: "this implies $g_k(x) \leq \bar{\varphi}(x)$ for all $k$, so $f(x) \leq \bar{\varphi}(x)$, which is a contradiction." That is the way to complete your argument.

Comment: why is that $g_k < \overline{ \phi} $ implies $f(x) \leq \overline{\phi} $ ?

Comment: You will notice that I was careful enough to put $f(x) \leq \bar{\varphi}(x)$. That is a less-than-or-equal-to sign. Anyhow, it is because the $g_k$ converge pointwise to $f$.

Comment: so pointwise convergence : $g_k \to f \implies f \leq g_k $ ?

Comment: If $g_{k}(x) \leq \bar{\varphi}(x)$, and $g_{k}(x) \to f(x)$, then $f(x) \leq \bar{\varphi}(x)$. This is simply how limits work.

Comment: for all $k$ ... ?

Comment: but In our case $g_k < \overline{ \phi} $ we cannot pass to the limit if we have $<$.

Comment: Yes. This is why I replaced it with a $\leq$.

Comment: Uhmm Im confused. If $x \notin A_k$, then we cannot have $g_k \geq \overline{ \phi } $ so we must have $ g_k < \overline { \phi } $

Comment: Right. But the contradiction comes when we introduce $f$, so we need to take a limit to go from $g_k$ to $f$. In the limit, the $<$ sign turns into a $\leq$ sign, but that still gives us a contradiction.

Comment: So you are saying $g_k < \overline{ \phi } \implies \lim g_k \leq \overline{ \phi } \implies f \leq \overline{ \phi } $ ?

Comment: Yes! That is correct! :)

Comment: So in general if we have any sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n < A $ , then we have $ \lim x_n \leq A $. But we dont have strict inequality ?

Comment: No. $-1/n < 0$ for all $n$, but in the limit $-1/n \to 0$.

Comment: thank you very much. One last question. In the proof above the author is assuming $f > 0 $ on $E$ wlog because if $f = 0$, then result follows at once right ?